# Experiment to show that current leads voltage by 90° in capacitor

Tags: electric-circuits, experimental-physics, capacitance, experimental-technique

I understand that current leads voltage by 90° in capacitor.
How does one show that it is true by an experiment?

Answer (score 2):

Use an [oscilloscope](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscilloscope).
Let one channel display the voltage across the capacitor.
Let a second channel display the voltage across a resistor, which you  have wired in series with the capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

I have designed a simple experiment to show that it is true within the experimental errors and wanted to know whether there is another method to show that it is true. (One of the experimental errors arises from the accuracy of my scope. )

I used a series RC circuit. R is 22k ohm. C is 0.01 micro farad. Source is 4Vpp with 500Hz/1000Hz/1500Hz Sine Wave.
My scope will jump from 148 micro second to 152 micro second (instead of 149 micro second) when I measured the phase difference using
cursor of scope. So, there is experimental error due to my accuracy of my scope.

My experimental result: 89.28 ° (500Hz)
90.72 ° (1000Hz)
89.46 ° (1500Hz)

Besides, I used 1.2 k ohm, 1 micro farad capacitor and 100 Hz Sine Wave. The result is 89.28 °

Answer (score 0):

I used the phasor diagram of RC circuit to analyse the experiment. If the angle between Vr and Vs is θ and
the angle between Vs and Vc is Φ . The addition of θ and Φ should be near to 90 °
( Vr : voltage of resistor;
Vs : voltage of source;
Vc : voltage of capacitor;
I : current )

Then, I found the angles of θ and Φ in the experiment.

Since Vr and I are in the same phase and the addition of θ and Φ is near to 90 ° ,
I showed that the current leads voltage by 90 ° in capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

If the accuracy of scope of somebody is better than the accuracy of my scope.
For example, if each jump of the cursor of scope is 1µ s ( Δ x/ Δ t), the angle would be 89.99 ° or 90 ° .
(Each jump of my scope is 4µ s)

Besides, my method to find θ and Φ is
(1) using high pass RC circuit to find θ
(2) then, using low pass RC circuit to find Φ (exchange the positions of resistor and capacitor in the circuit).

On the other hand, we need not exchange the positions of resistor and capacitor
but move the source, the ground lead , the probes of CH1 and CH2 to other positions of the circuit.
We can also find Φ.